# Color change during hover refuse to revert

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `div`, say `DivX` and i had written `hover` functionality for that in `css` to change its `background-color`. Additionally i had added a `jquery` animation effect for that to move its `left`. Now the problem is , whenever i'm cliking on `DivX`, `hover` effect taken place and animated perfectly on that, but the `background-color` changed during `hover` is refusing to turn back, until i move the `cursor`.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mN7L8/)

***Steps to reproduce:***

- Place the `cursor` over the `DivX`, You can see its `background-color` get changed.
- Make a click on it.[Note: Dont move the cursor.]
- Now You can see that, the `DivX` has animated to its new location, but its `background-color` remains the same.
- Now, Move the `mouse cursor`, you can notice the `background-color` change.

My question is, How can i make use of `Hover` functionality in my case with out any interruption.?

Comment: For me (Friefox 10.0.12) the elements changes back to old bg-color on click as the element moves out from under the cursor causing the hover condition to expire. Are you seeing this problem in a specific browser?

Comment: @MikeBrant, I'm testing this in ie9, let me check that out in FireFox.

Comment: I see this issue in Chrome. Hover bg is shown until I move a mouse after click.

Comment: @MikeBrant As you said, There is no problem with FireFox, But it is having problems with IE,Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I know it seems hacky, but you might try using jQuery for hover effects rather than plain CSS so that hopefully you get more consistent behavior across browsers.

Comment: Works fine in Firefox, Chrome and IE9 for me, although there was a slight delay on IE9 for the colour to change back, but it did so without moving the cursor.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, But this is a simple behaviour, i dont want to add this to my scripts. i need it to be accompolished by css.Any ideas.?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count = 0;
  $("#test").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({ "left": "200"}, 500 );
    if(!count){
      count++;
    $(this).css({'background-color':'orange'});
    }
  });  
  $("#test").hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color':'yellow'});
  }, function(){
  $(this).css({'background-color':'orange'});
  });

});
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/mN7L8/7/

Comment: The issue with this is that after clicking (and whilst still hovering for a short period) the background changes, maybe I'm just being a bit picky though.

Comment: i tried out your demo,but it also having a inconsistency. See , in the first click, it works fine, But while redoing the same thing(after gets animated), the color gets changed unnecessarily. tested in Ie,FF,Safari,Chrome.

Comment: Thank you, but for a hover functionality i am not ready to adopt this kind of complex solutions.Once again thanks for your support.

Comment: complex? :/ as in you'de prefer less JS and more css, or the actual JS is too complex?

Comment: I would prefer this way 'Less Js More benefits'. By the way Consuming a variable,an incrementation and an if statement looks bit lengthier..! :)

Comment: Well, i've tried the lot removing class and adding class http://jsfiddle.net/mN7L8/12/ and it seems my answer is your best bet

Comment: unfortunately, it is again repeating the problem that i was mentioned in my question.  tested in IE,Safari,Chrome

Comment: yes i know lol, im just saying it's a method ive tried and failed, my solution looks like the only

Comment: thanks for your interest over this, Any way i'll add an answer to this question, if i get any solutions.! :)

Comment: How about http://jsfiddle.net/mN7L8/14/ , this doesn't include the incrementation

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a workaround, and works in a similar fashion as Yusaf's answer.
Set a class that keeps the background orange when you hover, then use the "animate complete" callback to remove that class.  Once that class is removed, if you hover again you will get the desired result.

CSS:

```
#test.fix:hover, #test.fix{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#test").click(function(){ 
   $(this).animate({ "left": "200"}, 500, function(){ $(this).removeClass("fix");
   }).addClass("fix");
});
```